# How to solve linear system of equations using colt library in java

Tags: java, matrix, system, linear-algebra, colt

I want to solve the linear equation **matrix*X=D** using Colt library.
I tried :

```
DoubleMatrix2D matrix;
matrix = new DenseDoubleMatrix2D(4,4);
for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < 4; column++) {
        // We set and get a cell value:             
        matrix.set(row,column,row+column);          
    }
}
DoubleMatrix2D D;
D = new DenseDoubleMatrix2D(4,1);
D.set(0,0, 1.0);
D.set(1,0, -1.0);
D.set(2,0, 91.0);
D.set(3,0, -5.0);
DoubleMatrix2D X;
X = solve(matrix,D);
```

but I get an error
"The method solve(DoubleMatrix2D, DoubleMatrix2D) is undefined for the type Test" ,
where Test is the name of the class.

What have I done wrong?
Any ideas?...

Comment: Could you please add how you declare you `solve` method?

Comment: the _solve_ method is a method in library Colt, it's not mine. I just want to find out how to use it in my program...

Comment: Did you import Colt library in your class?

Comment: Yes,I have typed:

 `import cern.colt.matrix.*;

import cern.colt.matrix.impl.DenseDoubleMatrix1D;

import cern.colt.matrix.impl.DenseDoubleMatrix2D;`

Isn't that right?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are getting this error is because method `solve()` is non-static and can't be accessed from `main()`.

This should solve your problem:

```
Algebra algebra = new Algebra();
DoubleMatrix2D X = algebra.solve(matrix, D);
```

Comment: Nice, but when I run it I get the error :

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:` `Matrix is singular.`                                              `at cern.colt.matrix.linalg.LUDecompositionQuick.solve(Unknown Source)`
`at cern.colt.matrix.linalg.LUDecomposition.solve(Unknown Source)`
`at cern.colt.matrix.linalg.Algebra.solve(Unknown Source)`
 `at test.Test.main(Test.java:89)`

Answer (score 1):

You also can use [la4j](http://la4j.org) (Linear Algebra for Java) for this:

- For determined systems `m == n` which is actually, your case:

  ```
  // The coefficient matrix 'a'
  Matrix a = new Basic2DMatrix(new double[][] {
    { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 },
    { 4.0, 5.0, 6.0 },
    { 7.0, 8.0. 9.0 }
  });

  // A right hand side vector, which is simple dense vector
  Vector b = new BasicVector(new double[] { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 });

  // We will use standard Forward-Back Substitution method,
  // which is based on LU decomposition and can be used with square systems
  LinearSystemSolver solver = 
     a.withSolver(LinearAlgebra.FORWARD_BACK_SUBSTITUTION);

  Vector x = solver.solve(b, LinearAlgebra.DENSE_FACTORY);
  ```
- For overdetermined systems `m > n` the `LinearAlgebra.LEAST_SQUARES` solver can be used.

*All the examples are taken from official web-site: http://la4j.org*